# Ionic 4 - Atualizar um componente com dados de um modal?

Tags: angular, ionic, modal, ionic4

Estou desenvolvendo um app de pedidos online usando `Ionic 4`.
Esse app possui um sistema de benefícios. Quando o usuário abre o carrinho de compras ele pode abrir um `modal` onde são listados seus benefícios disponíveis.
Quando o usuário seleciona o benefício dentro do `modal`, esse benefício deve aparecer automaticamente no carrinho, quando o `modal` é fechado.

**carrinho.page.ts**

```
...
beneficio:any
...
  async mostraBeneficios(){
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: BeneficiosComponent,

    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
...
 carregaBeneficioSelecionado(){
    this.beneficio = this.beneficioService.getBeneficios()
    console.log(this.beneficio)
  }
...
```

**carrinho.page.html**

```
...
      <!-- Botao que mostra modal -->
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button (click)="mostraBeneficios()">
        <ion-icon icon="../assets/icon/tag.svg"></ion-icon>
        Beneficios
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
...
  <!-- Item que deve mostrar o beneficio após ser selecionado -->
  <ion-item *ngIf="beneficio">
    <ion-label> {{ beneficio.nome }} </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
...
```

Modal:
**beneficios.component.ts**

```
constructor(
    private modalController: ModalController,
    private firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider,
    private beneficiosService: BeneficiosService
  ) { 
    this.carregaBeneficios();
  }

  fechaModal(){
    this.modalController.dismiss();
  }
...
beneficios:any
...
  //  lista os beneficios disponiveis
  carregaBeneficios(){
    this.firebaseProvider.getBeneficios()
    .then((r) => {
      this.beneficios = r
    })
  }

  //captura o beneficio selecionado
  radioBeneficio($event){
    this.beneficiosService.setBeneficios($event.detail)
  }
```

**beneficios.component.html**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-radio-group name="auto">

      <ion-card *ngFor="let b of beneficios">
        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-item (ionSelect)="radioBeneficio($event)" lines="none">
            <ion-label text-left> {{ b.descricao }} </ion-label>
            <ion-label text-right>
              <ion-badge color="primary" mode="ios"> {{ b.pontos }} </ion-badge>
              <p>pontos</p>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-radio  [value]="b" color="success" slot="end"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>

        </ion-card-header>

      </ion-card>

    </ion-radio-group>
  </ion-list>


</ion-content>

<ion-footer class="footer">
  <ion-button class="btn-footer" fill="clear" expand="full" (click)="fechaModal()">
    Cancelar
  </ion-button>
</ion-footer>
```

Como posso atualizar o `<ion-item>` no **carrinho.page.html** automaticamente Quando o modal é fechado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem muitas formas de você fazer isso, poderia fazer utilizando os services/providers ou enviando um callback como input para o modal, vou te mostrar o exemplo do callback:

```
async mostraBeneficios(){
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: BeneficiosComponent,
  componentProps:{
      'callbackBeneficios': (beneficio) => {
          this.beneficio = beneficio
      }
  }
});
return await modal.present();
```

}

Basta adicionar um Input, que dei o nome de callbackBeneficio, e declara-lo no modal,
na documentação do ionic não encontrei forma de adicionar um Output no modal. Utilizo essa alternativa pois funciona muito bem.
Precisa adicionar o import do ***decorator Input*** do angular:

```
   @Input() callbackBeneficios;

    constructor(
        private modalController: ModalController,
        private firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider,
        private beneficiosService: BeneficiosService
      ) { 
        this.carregaBeneficios();
      }

      fechaModal(){
        this.modalController.dismiss();
      }
    ...
    beneficios:any
    ...
      //  lista os beneficios disponiveis
      carregaBeneficios(){
        this.firebaseProvider.getBeneficios()
        .then((r) => {
          this.beneficios = r
        })
      }

      //captura o beneficio selecionado
      radioBeneficio($event){
         this.callbackInput($event.detail)
        //this.beneficiosService.setBeneficios($event.detail)
      }
```

Você pode continuar utilizando o service tbm, mas como não adicionou o código do seu service vou adicionar como eu faria

```
    export class BeneficioService {

    beneficio$ = new Subject();

    getBeneficio(){
        return this.beneficio$.asObservable()
    }

    setBeneficio(data){
        this.beneficio$.next(data)
    }
  }
```

Dessa forma basta fazer um subscribe no carrinho.page.ts dentro do seu construtor:

```
    constructor( private beneficioService: BeneficioService ){
     this.beneficioService
      .getBeneficio()
    .  subscribe( res => this.beneficio = res )
   }
```

E retornar o trecho de código como estava antes

```
radioBeneficio($event){
       this.beneficiosService.setBeneficios($event.detail)
 }
```

Comment: Com o Observable funcionou perfeitamente, era minha ideia inicial, mas não sabia com implementar no código. Como o @Input, foi apresentado um erro no console quando clicava sobre o benefício: `Input is not a function`. Mas o problema foi resolvido com o Observable, obrigado.

Comment: O erro era pq eu no exemplo adicionei callbackInput e nao callbackBeneficios. Mas com observable funcionando sucesso !!